# Can I modify the `BlockHashCount` on my chain safely to change transaction mortality?

Tags: transactions, runtime-upgrade, genesis

### Background

Transaction Mortality is described on the [Polkadot Wiki](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/build-protocol-info#transaction-mortality) as:

> Extrinsics can be mortal or immortal... If the extrinsic is not
> included in a block within this validity window, it will be discarded
> from the transaction queue.
>
> **The chain** only stores a limited number of prior block hashes as reference. You can query this parameter, called `BlockHashCount`, from
> the chain state or metadata. This parameter [is set to 2400 blocks on
> Polkadot](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/975e780ae0d988dc033f400ba822d14b326ee5b9/runtime/common/src/lib.rs#L76-L92)
> (about four hours) **at genesis**...
>
> Setting the block checkpoint to zero, using the genesis hash, and a
> validity period of zero will make the transaction "immortal".

### Motivation

**I would like to change (increase or decrease) the maximal lifetime of a transaction in on my network.**

I see I can set the `BlockHashCount` on my chain in the [node template runtime](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/174735ea1bb5fc4513519c45181d8df63d86f613/bin/node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs#L134-L143) but the wiki implies that it cannot be changed from genesis. It also implies that this parameter affects much more than the behavior of the "cached" hashes on the node from the description above, so it's unclear why this may be unsafe to modify, or if there is another means to only change the behavior of what is the maximal validity period for a transaction to be included, at the runtime level, and (separately) at the transaction pool level.

### Question

**Is it safe to perform a runtime upgrade to update `BlockHashCount`, and if so, what side effects will this have?**

Answer (score 3):

How does the Wiki imply that changing it is unsafe?

Changing it will just affect the size of the storage trie under FRAME System. Since Substrate uses a base 16 trie, you'd have to go to a really high count to affect trie depth.

In fact, Kusama has already upgraded its `BlockHashCount`. At genesis, [it was 250](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/v0.7.2/runtime/src/lib.rs#L143).

The change: https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/pull/1086